# Media files found in development but not production pythonanywhere

Tags: python, django, media, production, pythonanywhere

I have a basic file upload system written using django. It works and the files are properly uploaded to the correct path. However, when using google drive viewer it comes up as preview not available. After some digging around I figured the problem must be that the url is not being found, which it is not.

In other words `mysite.pythonanywhere.com/media/files/myfile.pdf` returns a 404 error.
However, `http:127.0.0.1:8000/media/files/myfile.pdf` works perfectly fine (on local server of course). So this is a problem with serving the files in production.

My media url is correctly mapped to the media directory, as shown on the pythonanywhere help page.

```
URL = /media/  
DIRECTORY = /home/name/mysite/media
```

The files are saved in the correct place on the filesystem. My static files are served fine and have a near identical setup to the media files.

I've been trying to solve the problem for two days now but haven't found a solution. Any ideas?

In my settings.py:

```
MEDIA_ROOT = os.path.join(BASE_DIR, 'media')
MEDIA_URL ='/media/'
STATIC_ROOT = os.path.join(BASE_DIR, 'static')
STATIC_URL = '/static/'
```

It could be worth noting that when I intentionally place the wrong path to a static file, the 404 error doesn't include a list of urls which django has searched. It does in the  404 error messages for media. So the server is directly serving the static files without passing the request down to the wsgi layer, but for some reason it's not handling media urls the same way? By the way I am working with debug=False but only set it to True to help diagnose the problem. Here are the messages:

```
    Request Method: GET
    Request URL:http://infodump.pythonanywhere.com/static/randfile.txt
    'randfile.txt' could not be found

    Request Method: GET
    Request URL:    http://infodump.pythonanywhere.com/media/randfile.txt
    Using the URLconf defined in InfoDump.urls, Django tried these URL patterns,in this order:
    1.^admin/
    2.^streamer/
    3.^ ^$ [name='home_page']
    4.^ ^signUpPage/$ [name='sign_up']
    The current URL, media/randfile.txt, didn't match any of these.
```

Comment: Try to run python manage.py collectstatic on production server

Comment: It's not that unfortunately. I've done that and my static files (css, js, imgs) are served fine. The media files are already in the correct sub-directory so thats not the problem. I am considering placing the media files in the static folder as a workaround but that could be bad for security.

Comment: are you able to upload it successfully or not?

Comment: Yh I upload it through a form and it is successfully sent to the correct directory in the server. But I cant then access it.

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/38683105/404-on-media-files-django/38683329#38683329

Comment: Yep I had already set the mapping

Comment: PythonAnywhere dev here: did you reload the site on the "Web" tab after you set up the static files mapping?  If so, would you mind if I took a look at your site?  We can see everything from our side, but we always ask permission before looking at anyone's files.

Comment: Yh i reloaded it and checked if I could access the static files properly and that was fine, but the media files wouldn't load. Yh that's no problem, the projects name is infodump. Thanks.

Comment: It looks like it's configured correctly -- although http://infodump.pythonanywhere.com/media/randfile.txt doesn't work, that's because the file doesn't exist.  http://infodump.pythonanywhere.com/media/rand.txt does work...