# 404 on media files - Django

Tags: python, django, django-settings

Last night I uploaded my project to pythonanywhere.com where I wanted to test my **production** settings. In one of my models I allow **users to upload** JPG's (Logo of a team). The uploading process works good, the file lands in my MEDIA_ROOT. The issue is that when I try to access it in my template (to display it on the page) I get a 404. My first thought is that my MEDIA_URL is not configured properly but I still don't know why. I want to say that my media folder isn't in the project - it is outside.
On **development** mode I see the Logo (I have the if settings.DEBUG: urlpattern += static(...) option set properly).

I'm using Django 1.9.7 with python 2.7
Here is my code:

My model:

```
class Team(models.Model):

name = models.CharField(verbose_name='Name of the team', max_length=24)
logo = models.ImageField(upload_to='team_logos', verbose_name='Logo', blank=True, null=True)
def get_logo(self):
    u"""Get path to logo, if there is no logo then show default."""
    if self.logo:
        return self.logo.url
    return '/static/img/default_team_logo.jpg'
```

My Settings.py:

```
STATIC_URL = '/static/'
STATIC_ROOT = os.path.join(os.path.dirname(BASE_DIR), "media", "soccerV1", "static")
STATICFILES_DIRS = (
os.path.join(BASE_DIR, "media", "static"),
)
MEDIA_URL = '/media/'
MEDIA_ROOT = os.path.join(os.path.dirname(BASE_DIR), "media", "soccerV1", "media")
```

And my template where I call for the logo:

```
<td><img src="{{ details.get_logo }}" alt="{{ details.name }} logo" height="64px" width="64px"></td>
```

Comment: What have you configured to actually serve files from MEDIA_URL?

Answer (score 9, accepted):

You need to set a media files mapping in PythonAnywhere's dashboard. From their [documentation](https://help.pythonanywhere.com/pages/DjangoStaticFiles/):

- Go to the **Web** tab on the PythonAnywhere dashboard
- Go to the **Static Files** section
- Enter the same URL as MEDIA_URL in the **url** section (in your case, `/media/`)
- Enter the path from MEDIA_ROOT into the **path** section (the full path, including `/home/username/etc`)

Then hit **Reload** and your uploaded files should be served correctly.

Comment: Thanks @rafalmp - you really saved my day :) I was searching the pythonanywhere.com help section for something like that but I couldn't find it. Thanks again! :)